In a democratic society, should governments be allowed to pay for or fund artistic/cultural works and performances using taxpayers' money?
Especially considering that aesthetic criteria are essentially individual matters, and that certain works and performances may be regarded as offensive by some part of society
There is also a pragmatic argument that some such spending ends up generating money, employment, tourism and the like, but I'm more interested in the issue of "government acting as arbiter of taste", so to speak.

@Lowri answers are expected to pick some reference/framework and use them; this much should be obvious

You ask:

in a democratic society, should governments be allowed to pay for or fund artistic/cultural works and performances using taxpayers' money?

And in response to "'should' according to what standard?", you clarify that:

answers are expected to pick some reference/framework and use them

For this answer, I will pick and use the reference/framework of democratic legitimacy.
Under the framework of democratic legitimacy, governments should be allowed to pay for and fund artistic and/or cultural works using money that came from taxpayers. I am assuming that the taxation legislation was enacted by a democratically legitimate legislature, and that the government making the spending decisions is either elected directly (in a republic) or supported by Parliament (e.g. Canada or the U.K.).

That is the model. I just wonder if things aren't rather more complicated now than under previous democratic situations? And people less uniform in their preferences. What if we outgrow democracy?

In a sharply split society, there are no common values that people can trust their government to propagate into the masses. Republicans removed liberal books from school libraries in Florida, and so on.

This answer could be improved by explaining why democratically legitimate legislature helps justifying this (e.g. because it makes sure that the law furthers a common interest)

@wra is right: as is stands, this answer is a 'link-only answer', and not informative at all

@ac15 but what if it is the correct answer?

@ScottRowe [besides hume,] that's unlikely, given that are other frameworks that don't necessarily with the conclusion, as people have brought up on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/1cjagmb/in_a_democratic_society_should_governments_be/

A democratic government exists to implement the will of the population.
If the population wants there to be publicly available art, then the government should make it so.
If the population does not, they should not.
The problem is of course that "the population" is not a uniform group. They have different opinions on what is important and what is not. This is what makes democracy so difficult.
Weather Vane made a good comment to the question:

Maybe but to me (as said) the question extends to be more general: "Why
should my tax revenue be spent on anything I don't like?"

This is true.

We could have a system where people decide how their personal tax contributions will be allocated. Businesses want this power too, they already try to decide what medical care their employees can receive through the employer-funded healthcare. The highest form of government is for everyone to be dictator of their stuff, I guess. We just need a much larger planet.

the question is not so broad to include " 'anything' i don't like", read the first paragraph

@ScottRowe Businesses want this power too, they already try to decide what medical care their employees can receive through the employer-funded healthcare Perhaps you have a typo here? If it is employer funded, they have every right to decide how their money should be spent, unlike taxation, where others' money is in question.

A very good answer, and it brings us to the important question: what is the role of the elite in modern western democracy? Can the educated professional minority decide what is good for the less educated and even ignorant majority?

The Soviets tried that with mixed results. What was good for the people was bad for society as a whole. One system benefited the development of the human bean while the other stimulated economic growth. What is more important? Can you combine these systems?

@Vector perhaps the employer would be happier managing all aspects of their employees lives, like a Company Town? And perhaps the employees would be happier working for someone who doesn't meddle so obsessively in their personal life?

@ScottRowe - 1: perhaps the employer would be happier managing all aspects of their employees lives - how is that relevant to this discussion? 2: If the employer is paying for it, they are not meddling - it is intrinsically their business.  If an employee doesn't like the healthcare their employer provides, they are free to find another job, or provide for their own healthcare. 3: perhaps employees would be happier working for someone... Nothing stopping employees from doing so. If they like other aspects of the job but not the healthcare, they indeed have a choice to make.

@ScottRowe perhaps the employer would be happier managing all aspects of their employees lives, like a Company Town?  So what? An employer may set their own conditions for employment, within the bounds of the law. (I had a potential employer who insisted I move to their location, so I opted not to take that job.) If nobody wants to work under their stipulated conditions, they will have to change their policies or go out of business.

@Vector the employer cannot regulate things that are legal in the healthcare system, that's why we have a government that decides those things. People might have to take what jobs they can get, and we have to protect vulnerable people from those who overstep their authority. Triangle Shirtwaist factory? Buildings wrapped in flashpaper cladding? Whom would you make a wedding cake for, and whom not? What would you do if asked? Could you refuse or not?

Why doesn't the employer get out of the healthcare thing and simply pay enough that employees could get their own? A couple thousand dollars a month should do it, for one person, or four thousand for a family.

@ScottRowe - perhaps you missed what I said? within the bounds of the law.

@ScottRowe - Why doesn't the employer get out of the healthcare thing... I have been advocating for that for many years - personally it would be much better for my situation. I don't recall at the moment the entire story of how healthcare in the US came to be linked with employment, but this appears to be an informative page on the subject:  Origins and Evolution of Employment-Based Health Benefits

@Vector I guess we will need to vote on it: Can companies micromanage their employees' purchase of legal things using money the employer gave them? If you give someone money or something, that means you have to open your hand and let go of it. Otherwise, don't 'give'.

@ScottRowe If you give someone money or something, that means you have to open your hand and let go of it Not necessarily. One can give money with a stipulation: "I'm giving you the money for some particular reason". Such is common practice, in law and legislation and everyday life. One can give a gift or make a will with a stipulation. Congress regularly allocates funds with stipulations. Parents give allowances with stipulations. So can an employer. It's not necessarily micromanaging - it is often done with good purpose. But it remains a gift - something you gave -  not a loan.

@Vector I would say, "thanks, but no thanks." Don't people have better things to do with their time than tell other people what to do?

Yes, because if you take the German perspective (Read The Management of Opera by Agid on European opera funding model, for example), art exists outside of the profit arena and in the “being mode”. People need to go to places of belonging, and exchange perspectival learning. This is thought along the lines of philosophers like Erich Fromm. Art should be subsidized as public good and protected by free speech in order to give tools to critique power, to “become”, to integrate, etc. - the being mode

If the German government paid for music, could they also order the music? Meaning, if they pay money, can they also choose what is good for people and what is not so good?

In popular culture (music, movies, TV shows), the lowest denominator is always beating real high art, similar to fast food.

Stupidification of the masses is a big problem that no one talks about.

"And what is good, @TheMatrixEquation-balance, and what is not good. Need we ask anyone to tell us these things?"

@ScottRowe - "Need we ask anyone" - Asking questions is not the biggest obstacle. How would you get the most gifted and brightest to work in education and culture, in the US, for example?

In the USSR it was quite straightforward. Make the salary of a skilled worker twice more than that of a doctor or engineer - and you would stimulate the best brains in the nation to do something more useful: write poetry or music or create movies.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance the problem was that in the USSR, after a while they blamed all the smart people and then imprisoned or killed them. Not a good incentive system. Lots of people in the USA have been blamed unfairly also. Don't bite the hand that's getting enough food to grow, and making electricity for the fridge, and healing your sick children, and and and... We deserve what we create and support. If we cut support for things that help, we deserve to fail. Evolution always wins.

@ScottRowe - I don't believe in evolution when it comes to humans. "Survival of the fittest" would not play well with trends for technological progress in the 21st century. But we've been tested, Trump is still on the horizon. And what used to be just funny about people's ignorance, now turns out to be outright dangerous.

"May you live in interesting times"

This is an extremely important question.
But this topic is taboo in American politics even though their model of imported (by European immigrants) culture and values does not work anymore.
A large portion of people in the US grow up like grass, with an absolute minimum of cultural and intellectual background. If you don't agree with me, just watch what kids watch on TV.
At the same time, any investment from the government in good books, good movies, good music for kids - is considered propaganda and strictly prohibited.
But as always, there is a positive side to it. A lot of Americans try to fill this cultural and intellectual void by putting all their energy into their professional activities.

Yes, we are surpassing Japan in deaths from overwork.

When I was younger, I was afraid of the Mad Max world. But we ran out of sense before we ran out of oil.

If we develop fusion, there's no limit. We could go on for millions of years.

@ScottRowe - In digital format and quantum computers :)

@ScottRowe for some, at least as far as Golgafrincham.

@WeatherVane "The real reason we're trying to send humans to Mars"

In digital format, each person could have an individual Disneyland and would not have to interact with or agree with anyone. There would be no need for government or public spaces.

@ScottRowe - I agree with you. And the only issue they would have to overcome is how not to be bored in their millions-year existence.

Larry Niven covered that to some degree in "A World Out Of Time"

@ScottRowe - "human species has fragmented; it is dominated by a race of immortal, permanently pre-adolescent males (the Boys), who are created by advanced medical techniques. Some time in the past, they had defeated the equally immortal (though now extinct) Girls, in the ultimate war of the sexes." - A cruel twist :))

This does not answer the question. Instead it is a comment on American society, for which politics.stackexchange.com would be a better fit.

@wra - Philosophy is like a family doctor, and treats all kinds of disorders.
